# Changing string with same variable name in for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop

Let's understand this scenario within example below:

```
for(int i=1; i<15; i++){

   if(i == 1){
      String animalName = "cat";
   }

   if(i == 5){
      String animalName = "dog";
   }

   if(i == 10){
      String animalName = "elephant";
   }
}
```

I want to change string within same variable name inside for loop?
How to achieve this?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't get the question. Where exactly do you want to change what?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve here? Can you please explain

Comment: That is declaring 3 different variables in 3 different non-overlapping scopes, so they have nothing in common, even though they happen to have the same name. To be the *same* variable, you have to declare it once, *outside* the 3 `if` statements, e.g. `String animalName = null;`, then just *assign* values inside the `if` statements, e.g. `animalName = "cat";`. You should re-read your handy Java guide about variables and variable scope, or search the web for [`java variable scope`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+variable+scope) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
for(int i=1; i<15; i++) {
    String animalName;
    if(i == 1) {
        animalName = "cat";
    }
    if(i == 5) {
        animalName = "dog";
    }
    if(i == 10) {
        animalName = "elephant";
    }
}
```